# Smooth domain $\Omega$

Tags: maximum-principle, elliptic-equations, smooth-functions, domain-theory

A smooth domain $\Omega$ is an open and connected subset of the whole domain, say $\mathbb{R}^n$, of which the boundary $\partial \Omega$ is "smooth".

The smoothness of the boundary, intuitively speaking, is:

> The boundary of a smooth domain can be viewed as the graph of a smooth function locally.

My question is, why is the **smoothness** of $\partial \Omega$ related to the function smoothness? Can I have pls a **simple** example or explanation?

Comment: The explanation is super simple. Why? Because we define it that way. Do you have another definition of smooth boundary that you like more?

Comment: @WoolierThanThou But why for example is the boundary smoothness essential for the normal derivative?

Comment: Well, that boils down to whatever your definition of the normal derivative is. Usually, it's the derivative with respect to the normal vector of the boundary so that boils down to the definition of the normal vector. Usually, you'd want the normal vector to be a vector which is orthogonal to the tangent plane of the boundary at every point so you'd need a definition of smooth boundary which implies the existence of a meaningful tangent plane at every point. But that's *exactly* equivalent to the boundary being the graph of some smooth function.

Comment: I know its by definition like this, but I can't understand the concept, or even the relation between smoothness of the boundary and that of the function. Can I have some help plz?